# How to plot a data in matplot only if the y values is greater than 50

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using matplotlib animation. However, I only want to use the animation only if the y_values appended from the random randint is above 50. Hence, my graph will only show the y values with 50 and above.

Does anyone have any example codes or solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing could be helpful here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make data
x_data = np.linspace(0,5,100)
y_data = np.cos(x_data)

# Remove the values below zero here
y_positive = y_data[y > 0]
x_positive = x_data[y > 0]

# plot of original
plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'o')
plt.savefig('original_data.png')
plt.clf()

# plot of new, corrected data
plt.plot(x_positive,y_positive,'o')
plt.savefig('positive_only.png')
plt.clf()
```

Another, simpler solution is to just cutoff the range at the minimum value like so:

```
plt.ylim(low_value,high_value)
```